# Without any built-in looping macro, can we just use a recursive macro to get a-b-c-d-e?

Tags: macros, expansion, plain-tex

Without any built-in looping macro, can we just use a recursive macro to get an output of `a-b-c-d-e`?

```
\def\aaa #1{#1-\aaa}
\aaa abcde
% expected result : a-b-c-d-e
\bye
```

### Edit:

Probably the best way to invoke `\aaa` should be `\aaa{abcde}` so the condition to terminate the recursion is still an open question.

Comment: In plain, `\bye` is `\outer` so can't be in the argument to another macro

Comment: @JosephWright: I finalized the scanning with `\relax` but it does not help as well. :-)

Comment: Wasn't quite my point: it's a lot easier to terminate a loop if the token after can simply be grabbed, whereas if it's `\outer` life is not so straight-forward. What are the rules here for detecting the end of the list for recursion?

Comment: @JosephWright: `\relax` might be used to terminate the recursion with `\if` probably.

Comment: If you leave an empty line before `\bye` you'll receive an error too: `Runaway argument?` and 
`! Paragraph ended before \aaa was complete.` Your recursion is endless.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 It's _your_ question: please define the conditions for termination!

Comment: Maybe repeat the last letter to tell TeX to finish the loop: `\aaa{abcdee}` to produce `a-b-c-d-e`.

Comment: You have offered bounties for the most large amount of rep I ever seen. 51,900 rep. Oh...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the argument of `\aaa` is expected to be a string of characters, then

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\aaa#1{\a@a#1\@nil}
\def\a@a#1{\ifx#1\@nil\expandafter\empty\else#1-\expandafter\a@a\fi}
\catcode`@=12

\aaa{abcde}

\bye
```

will do. If the argument is more complicated, with braced groups or macros, it's more difficult.

This is fully expandable, and `\edef\foo{\aaa{abcde}}\show\foo` would output

```
> \foo=macro:
->a-b-c-d-e-.
```

Your first try can't work, because there's no termination condition.

Adding support for braced groups and removing the trailing `-` can be done as follows:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\q@stop{\q@stop}
\def\q@nil{\q@nil}
\long\def\@gobble#1{}
\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\aaa#1{\aa@#1\q@stop\q@nil}
\def\aa@#1#2{%
  \ifx\q@stop#2%
    #1\expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    #1-\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@gobble}%
  {\aa@{#2}}%
}
\catcode`@=12

\aaa{abcde}

\aaa{a{bc}de}

\bye
```

Note that `\aa@` has two arguments, so we can absorb a group; the testing is done on the second argument, stopping the recursion if it is `\q@stop`. I leave as an exercise the case of `\aaa{}`.

Comment: The code is curious. First: the `\expandafter\empty` is redundant. Second: `\ifx#1\@nil` is equivalent to `\ifx#1\undefined` because `\@nil` isn't defined in `plain.tex`. The catcode changing of `@` is redundant too.

Comment: @wipet I added `\expandafter\empty` just for symmetry. Why should be the catcode change redundant?

Comment: IMHO, you can use `\undefined` instead `\@nil` and `\aXa` instead `\a@a`.

Comment: @wipet Sorry, no. Using `@` commands is *recommended* for macros the user shouldn't be aware of.

Comment: Sorry, using `@` commands is _bad_ decision. It doesn't prevent to end user to write `\def\def` or `\def\hbox`, it brings only complication and the legibility of macros are very reduced.

Comment: @wipet Yes, all macro writers in the last thirty-five years are wrong.

Comment: You are partially right. Many (but not all) macro writers follows this bad decision (by Knuth), especially LaTeX macro writers. But this is plain TeX. The reduced legibility is good shown in your second macro code: this macro code does the same work as my solution simply written on three lines.

Comment: There is plenty of redundant code in your second try. First: the `\def\@@a` is unused. Second: the empty parameter isn't solved, so `\q@nil` appended in `\aaa` is redundant. Of course, you need to define `\@gobbletwo` and use it instead `\@firstoftwo`, you need remove braces around `\aa@{#1}` and remove `{\@gobble}` and `\expandafter\@secondoftwo`. Finally, you can remove definition of `\@firstoftwo`, `\@secondoftwo` and `\@qnil`. After removing this redundant code the rest will work the same.

Comment: @wipet I don't think that questioning my programming style can lead to something. Thanks for spotting the useless line that had remained from old code.

Comment: @wipet I disagree: the `@` *per se* is not what's making macros illegible. It's the way some people use it: `\foo`, `\f@o`, and `\f@@` is hard to read while `\foo`, `\foo@auxi`, and `\foo@auxii` is not. And the `\def\def` thing: not being able to have *complete* safety doesn't make it bad idea to have at least *some* safety net IMHO.

Comment: @wipet: Maybe the idea of Knuth to use `@` was that users are guaranteed to be safe when they define macros which do not contain `@`?
So, the users are completely free to define any macros, except all standard macros from the format that they use.
In other words, if you do not use `@` in your macros, you do not have to check if it is free or not (considering that you know all the standard macros from the format and packages that you use).
IMHO, Knuth used `@` not as a protection mechanism, but as a convenience mechanism.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Users are not safe. Suppose, that a user knows `\it` `\bf` `\bye`, `\def` etc. but doesn't know `\hss`. He write `\def\hss{something}` and output routine will not work. And `@` is not for convenience, it brings only inconvenience.

Answer (score 12):

The following example uses the space as terminator and supports grouping of letters with braces including empty braces. The solution is expandable:

```
\def\aaa#1 {%
  \aaaX#1\empty\empty
}
\def\aaaX#1#2{%
  #1%
  \ifx\empty#2\longempty
    \expandafter\gobble
  \else
    -% 
    \expandafter\aaaX
  \fi
  {#2}%
}
\long\def\longempty{}
\long\def\gobble#1{}

%%% test %%%

\def\test#1{%
  \immediate\write16{[\noexpand\aaa #1 ] => [\aaa #1 ]}%
}
\test{abcde}
\test{a}  
\test{}   
\test{aaa}
\test{x{}{yy}}
\bye
```

Result:

```
[\aaa abcde ] => [a-b-c-d-e]
[\aaa a ] => [a]
[\aaa  ] => []
[\aaa aaa ] => [a-a-a]
[\aaa x{}{yy} ] => [x--yy]
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @egreg includes a mistake: the hyphen after the last letter isn't expected by the author of the question. There is full expanable solution which solves it:

```
\def\aaa #1{\ifx\end#1\end\else \aaaB #1\end\fi}
\def\aaaB #1#2\end{#1\aaaC#2\end} 
\def\aaaC #1{\ifx\end#1\empty\else -#1\expandafter\aaaC \fi}

\aaa {abcde}

\bye
```

Edit: I've added one `\ifx` in order to accept empty parameter. Grouping of letters with braces including empty braces is supported too.

Comment: The trailing `-` was there when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @egreg stackexchange uses a transaction database, all changes are simply traced. But I cannot find the mentioned change in the question.

Comment: @wipet http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/188225/1

Comment: Why are we trying to prove ourselves to this user for a stupid hyphen ?

Comment: Note that although this style of conditional code looks simpler than the other answers here, having the contents of your recursion macros execute inside the conditionals can cause problems in other contexts.

Comment: @WillRobertson Could you be more specific? Is there a situation where my macro doesn't work and other codes mentioned here do? The recursion is basic principle of all loops in TeX and this was mentioned in question explicitly.

Comment: Depends what you mean by ‘work’. Consider `\aaa {\iftrue abc\fi xyz \iffalse def\fi}`. Heiko's solution has a more sensible result (`-a-b-c--x-y-z`) than yours (`xyz`).

Comment: @WillRobertson In both cases (my and Heiko's code) this is bad usage of the macro. Suppose `\the\hsize` as the parameter (for example). If there is a need to do something like you show then user have to expand the parameter first before processing: `\edef\tmp{...}\expandafter\aaa\expandafter{\tmp}`.

Comment: @wipet — All I'm saying is that *in general* the pattern `\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\@secondoftwo\fi{true}{false}` is more robust. (Sorry about the slow reply; I don't know what tex.sx didn't tell me about your reply for four days.)